What is the largest known "computational" ordinal
I am interested in the computational implementation of ordinals. What I mean by that, is a data structure T and a function/algorithm "compare" that takes two arguments of type "T" and returns -1,0 or 1.
I am aware of computational implementations of ordinals up to epsilon 0.
What is the largest ordinal you can think of such that a computational implementation exists and can you provide a description of what this implementation looks like.
EDIT : Any ordinal (much) larger than epsilon 0 would be ok. I want to see what conceptual leap is needed to implement larger ordinals than epsilon 0, which I known can be implemented as a tree structure and some carefully crafted comparison operation between trees.

Hi Ivan, welcome to the site. You may want to search for "computable/recursive ordinals". I think there is no largest such ordinal, because the successor of any computable ordinal is computable (but there is a smallest noncomputable ordinal!). Perhaps this will be of interest to you. Generally "ordinal notation" is a computable way to get ordinals way beyond $\epsilon_0$. This is also a fairly concrete description of some very large computable ordinals.

Thank you Issak, yes your first link basicaly answers my question. The only issue is that I'm not able to undestand how you go from these mathematical definitions to an actual computer algorithm.
